# If product of two functions is holomorphic do they both have to be?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have two simple questions I just can't figure out:

- If $uv$ is holomorphic, then do $u$ and $v$ have to be holomorphic?
- If $uv$ and $u$ are holomorphic, then does $v$ have to be holomorphic?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $v$ is not holomorphic (say, $v(z)=\overline z$) and $u=0$, then $uv$ is holomorphic, which means the answer to both questions is **NO**.

---

**However:**

If $uv$ is holomorphic and $u$ is holomorphic and nonzero, then $v=uv\cdot\frac1u$ is also holomorphic.

Comment: Oh my! I thought that it can be easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: @wroobell It's only easy once you get used to it, so don't feel too bad. Interestingly, the same answer I gave is still true if you replace the word "holomorphic" with "continuous".